# Better way to create FloatArray in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
val matrix: FloatArray = emptyArray<Float>().toFloatArray()
```

This definitely works, it just looks pretty ugly. Is there no method to create `XXXArray` directly? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have three options for creating a FloatArray:

```
val arr1 = floatArrayOf(.1f)
val arr2 = FloatArray(12)
```

And, as you are doing already, `emptyArray`.

`floatArrayOf` works exactly like you'd expect; creates an array of the items with a corresponding size. It works just like `arrayOf`, just with a different return type.

The second one creates one defined by size. I just set the size to 12 as a demo, but you get the idea. The second one is roughly equivalent to `float[] arr2 = new float[12];`.

By default, it sets all the values to 0, but you can customize that with `FloatArray(12) { 1f }`, where `1f` can be any number you want to initialize all the items in the array as. You don't need that if you just want to set it to 0 though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [floatArrayOf](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/float-array-of.html) method to create such an array, as described in [the documentation](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays).